# Find all the <input type="number"> on a page in a browser that doesn't support them

Tags: javascript, html, html-input, polyfills, shim

I want to write a shim for older browsers that don't support `<input type="number">`.

This is easy to detect as, in those browsers, any `input` where you set the `type` to `number` will report the `type` as `text`. So good so far.

So what I want to do is find every `<input type="number">` and hook up events for these older browsers.

The problem is: how do I find them?

- `$('input[type=number]').length === 0` (of course).
- `$('input[name=aKnownNumberField]')[0].type === 'text'` again, not a surprise as this is the check used for feature detection in the first place.
- `$($('input[name=aKnownNumberField]')[0]).parent().html().indexOf('type="number"')` (or any similar check of the HTML) also fails because the HTML returned will be that according to the browser's DOM.

Note that I'm using jQuery in my examples, but I'm happy for non-jQuery answers.

How do I detect `<input type="number">` in browsers that don't support them?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("input[type='number']")`

Comment: @Cherniv `querySelectorAll` isn't supported by the very browsers Keith is trying to target.

Comment: Would you mind putting an extra attribute on the elements...like `data-input-type="number"`? Then you could get them by `$('input[data-input-type="number"]')`

Comment: @Cherniv a lot of the browsers that don't support `<input type="number">` also [don't support `querySelectorAll`](http://caniuse.com/queryselector). For instance it won't work in IE6 or IE7

Comment: @Ian I could. Marker styles are also an option, but I'm really looking for a shim/polyfill that I can add to my global JS without having to edit every page.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what `.getAttribute("type")` would return in comparison to just `.type`, but in the case that `.getAttribute("type")` returns "number" while `.type` returns "text", maybe try: `$("input").filter(function () { return this.getAttribute("type") === "number"; });`

Comment: @Keith Check this out - http://btburnett.com/2010/04/detecting-html5-input-types-on-unsupported-browsers.html

Comment: @Ian `$('input[name=aKnownNumberField]')[0].getAttribute('type') === 'text'` unfortunately :(

Comment: @Keith I don't see that happening. Try viewing this page in IE8 (or whatever): http://jsfiddle.net/DCqwA/show/ . The second `input` is `type="number"`, so the second `alert` **should** be `number number`. But in IE8 (and those that don't support it), the alert shows `text number`. The code is looping through all `input` elements and doing this: `alert(this.type + ", " + this.getAttribute("type"));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can get them using `.filter()`:

```
var $unsupported = $('input').filter(function() {
    return this.type !== $(this).attr('type');
});
```

This'll select *all* unsupported inputs, so you may want to filter that further using `.filter('[type="number"]')` or do that from within the filtering function.

A pure JS solution isn't much different:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type === inputs[i].getAttribute('type')) {
        continue;
    }

    // inputs[i] isn't supported by the browser
}
```

And a demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/PENRD

I tested it in IETester and it worked down to IE6.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that it does work in old IE, but not in IE9 or 10 in legacy mode - in IE10 as IE7 it fails, in IE7 it works. Lovely :-S

Comment: @Keith I've found many things not working with IE10 and compatibility mode...it's a pain

Answer (score 1):

```
$.expr[':'].realtype = function(objNode,intStackIndex,arrProperties,arrNodeStack)
{
  return $(objNode).attr('type')===arrProperties[3];
}

var numbers=$('input:realtype("number")');
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kingmotley/3sMQf/2/